# PHP won't update +1 value on mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$sql="UPDATE users SET TN4='1', Notificare4='1', Neachitate='1' WHERE username='$user'";
```

This works fine. It sets Neachitate row into 1. But, I want to set it to $Neachitate+ 1  ( +1 value, like each time you click it adds one more)

So, I modified it with

```
$Neachitate = $row['Neachitate']; // it gets what value is in Neachitate, right?

    $sql3="UPDATE users SET TN4='1', Notificare4='1', Neachitate='$Neachitate + 1' WHERE username='$user'";
```

But this time it sets to 0.  Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
$sql3="UPDATE users SET TN4='1', Notificare4='1', Neachitate=Neachitate + 1 WHERE username='$user'";
```

instead.

You're trying to save `Neachitate='$Neachitate + 1'`: this is a string, not a number.

Answer (score 1):

More generally, eliminate the single quotes!  And use parameters!

```
UPDATE users
    SET TN4 = 1,
        Notificare4 = 1,
        Neachitate = ? + 1
    WHERE username = ?;
```

Single quotes should only be used for string and date constants.  Parameters should always be used for passing constant values into queries.

Comment: thank you for your time and explications. I'll learn better from stackoverfllow than any school / studies. Yeah, if only I wouldn't get downvotes because I don't understand something and asking it (even if I read something close to my question and still don't get it.)